# How can i use get_queryset()object 'list_object' in other fuction

Tags: python, django, generics, django-models, django-views

```
class AboutView(ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = Product

    def get_queryset(self):
       
        object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        
        return object_list
    
    def get(request, self):
        new_list = object_list
        return new_list.order_to(-'price')
```

Comment: A question is not just a bunch of code, although your question title might say what you want, you should also add a description in the question body itself. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your purpose .i think use `self.get_queryset()`. More detail: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are trying to do:

```py
class AboutView(ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = Product

    def get_queryset(self):
       
        object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        
        return object_list
    
    def get(request, self):
        new_list = self.get_queryset()
        return new_list.order_to(-'price')
```

You cannot access `object_list` the way you are trying to, instead you should get it from the `get_queryset` method.